# Setting the content property dynamically using a custom property XAML WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm creating an onscreen keyboard for a touch screen app, where shift toggles upper and lower case buttons on the whole keyboard.

The code in the c# is working but I don't know how to change the content value and command parameter of the buttons based on on my custom property which changes on a bool value, in xaml.

```
<local:KeyboardButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Command="{Binding AddText}" Content ="{Binding local:KeyboardButton.SelectedKey}" LowerCaseKey="`" UpperCasekey="¬"/>
```

This is what I have currently for each button in the XAML (ignore the Content, as I've been grasping at straws here), the idea is that the shift key will toggle the Content and CommandParameter between the LowerCaseKey and UpperCaseKey properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you could achieve your goal with styles and triggers:

```
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Command="{Binding AddText}" x:Name="AButton">
        <Button.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Path=LowerCaseKey, ElementName=AButton}" />
                <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=LowerCaseKey, ElementName=AButton}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsUpperCase}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Path=UpperCasekey, ElementName=AButton}" />
                        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=UpperCasekey, ElementName=AButton}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Resources>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Custom Control:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Test
{
    public class KeyboardButton : Button
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedKeyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedKey", typeof(string),
            typeof(KeyboardButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsUpperCaseProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsUpperCase", typeof(bool),
            typeof(KeyboardButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

        static KeyboardButton()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(KeyboardButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(KeyboardButton)));
        }


        public string SelectedKey
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(SelectedKeyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedKeyProperty, value); }
        }


        public string LowerCaseKey
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string UpperCaseKey
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public bool IsUpperCase
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsUpperCaseProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsUpperCaseProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Themes\Generic.xaml (file Generic.xaml in the Themes folder)

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test">


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:KeyboardButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"> 
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding LowerCaseKey, Mode=OneTime, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsUpperCase" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding UpperCaseKey, Mode=OneTime, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Don't forget this in AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
    //(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
    // or application resource dictionaries)
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly //where the generic resource dictionary is located
    //(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
    // app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
)]
```